# User defined functions in jQuery + Delay

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
function rotate(x){
  $('#card').css({
    transform: 'rotate('+x+')'
  })
}

$(function(){
  $('#rotation-test').click(function(){
    rotate('3600deg').delay(15000).rotate('-36000deg');
  })
});
```

What I want to do is to call function rotate when element is clicked. Then wait 15 sec, and call same function again (with different param). I am aware this is not legit. How would I get the same effect?

Comment: That's not chaining. And you can do it with `setTimeout`: `setTimeout(function() {$('#rotation-test').trigger('click');}, 15000);`

Comment: I tought maybe there is another approach without using setTimeout but as I can see there is not, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As people commented to my question, there seems to be no other way than using setTimeout, so this is how I did it in case someone gets same problem.

```
function rotate(x){
  $('#card').css({
    transform: 'rotate('+x+')'
  })
}

$(function(){
  $('#rotation-test').click(function(){
    setTimeout(rotate,0,'3600deg');
    setTimeout(rotate,10000,'-3600deg');
  })
});
```